# Designing model file in hyperledger composer

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Considering a bank scenario , where participants are customers and transaction is money transfer , it can be as

> asset Account identified by accountId{
>       o String accountId
>       --> Customer owner
>       o Double balance
>       }
>       transaction AccountTransfer {
>       --> Account from
>       --> Account to
>        o Double amount
>      }

But what if there are different types of Participants who holds accounts. Like one can only transfer(sender) and while other can only receive(receiver)?How to solve this as account cant have two types of owners.

Can this be like this?

> asset account identified by accountId{
>       o String accountId 
>       o Double balance
>       }
>       Participant sender identified by sid{
>       --> Account account
>       o String sId
>       }
>       Participant receiver identified by rid{
>       --> Account account
>       o String rId
>       }
>       Transaction send {
>       -->Sender sender
>       -->Receiver receiver
>       }

Is it appropriate to design the model like above?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work.

To be sure that only the sender can execute a transfer, you can implement a logic in the transaction processor, which arise an exception if the participant that is invoking the transaction is not a "sender".

**Model**

```
asset account identified by accountId{
    o String accountId
    o Double balance
}

Participant sender identified by sid{
    --> Account account
    o String sId
}

Participant receiver identified by rid{
    --> Account account
    o String rId
}

Transaction send {
    -->Sender sender
    -->Receiver receiver
}
```

**TP**

```
async function send(tx) {  
    if (currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedType() !== 'org.example.sender') {
      // Throw an error as the current participant is not a sender.
      throw new Error('Current participant is not a sender');
    }

    //Other business logics
}
```

Otherwise you can implement a rule in the access control file which allow to transfer money only if who is invoking the transaction is a sender

```
rule AllowSenderToTransferMoney {
    description: "Sender can transfer money"
    participant(m): "org.example.sender"
    operation: ALL
    resource(v): "org.example.account"
    transaction(tx): "org.example.send"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: would endorse the ACL rule as the cleaner approach - as its not implemented in the transaction logic and 'clusers' authorization rules there in one place.